# How to run swissrannger camera (sr4500) on Ubuntu?

Tags: ethernet, camera

I am new in Ubuntu. I tried to run swissranger camera (sr4500 camera, it has Ethernet cable not usb) on Ubuntu 16.04 and also 14.04. I followed this tutorial "http://visionlab.uncc.edu/dokuwiki/using_the_mesa_sr4000_with_ros_indigo"
.After installing the drivers of the camera, I tried to run the camera on Ubuntu. When I run this code (sudo /usr/bin/libMesaSRTester), I can scan my camera without any errors, but it can not find my camera and I can not run it. How can I solve this issue? 
Should I change or edit anything else for running the camera on Ubuntu?

Thanks,

Abbas

When I scanned my camera, I got this:

```
CTestSRCustomer:
 1: TestBasic
 2: TestDataDump
 3: TestContinousAcquire
 4: TestUserSrvCmd
 5: TestTrial
----------------
x: exit

press a key
****001**** Testing CTestSRCustomer::Trial  ****001**** Testing SR_OpenDlg  
>>>>   >>>> CMesaDeviceFactory::OpenLastCam() not supported in Linux
>>>>   >>>> CM_CAM_SELECT->CP_CS_OPENDLG
-------------------------------------------------------
x: exit
s: scan

press a key
>>>>   >>>> CM_CAM_SELECT->CP_SCAN_CAM
>>>>   >>>> CM_CAM_SELECT->CP_FOUND_CAM
Camera File Stream
usb_set_debug: Setting debugging level to 255 (on)
usb_os_find_busses: Found 004
usb_os_find_busses: Found 003
usb_os_find_busses: Found 002
usb_os_find_busses: Found 001
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 004
skipping descriptor 0x30
skipped 1 class/vendor specific endpoint descriptors
usb_os_find_devices: Found 005 on 003
usb_os_find_devices: Found 004 on 003
usb_os_find_devices: Found 003 on 003
usb_os_find_devices: Found 002 on 003
skipped 1 class/vendor specific interface descriptors
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 003
error obtaining child information: Inappropriate ioctl for device
error obtaining child information: Inappropriate ioctl for device
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 002
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 001
usb_set_debug: Setting debugging level to 0 (off)
-------------------------------------------------------
1: Camera Camera File Stream
x: exit
s: scan

press a key
>>>>   >>>> CM_CAM_SELECT->CP_CONNECT
>>>>   >>>> CM_CAM_SELECT->CP_GET_FILENAME
Input file name to load:
```